# Clean data before inserting to table

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have my JPA  Entity something like below.

```
Employee{

String name;

String address;

String phoneNumber;

Date  joiningDate;

boolean isActive;

}
```

I am seeing that we have bad data inserted in the table for address,name like bad  characters  \u000b which is new line character.I want to handle this generically to cleanse the data before inserting.
I wanted to handle in dao layer because this gets called from many places hence want to handle at one central place.Some thing like AOP
I am  doing

```
employeeDao.save(employee);
```

which then  does `employee.merge();`

Comment: maybe see https://jsoup.org/cookbook/cleaning-html/whitelist-sanitizer

Comment: Thanks but users might enter wrong value from REST API also there are numerous entry points  so I feel better to sanitize at back end

Comment: Do you want to delete all the existing records and insert as fresh every time ? OR you want to delete only particular bad records what you have mentioned ? Or Looking for something which doesn't insert bad chars?

Comment: I do not want to delete I just want to strip this characters before inserting to table.Is there any aop advice i can do this in generic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a method annotated with @PrePersist or @PreUpdate to your entity to clean up your data. This method will be called automatically before every insert or update.

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.PrePersist;
import javax.persistence.PreUpdate;

@Entity
public class MyEntity{

   @PrePersist
   @PreUpdate
   private void cleanup() {
       ...correct your data here...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not the responsibility of the dao/domain layer to validate the data, rather the presentation and/or business layers. So check the data at the client or one of the controllers from the business layer and just call the domain layer with validated data (or throw an EInvalidXXXX exception)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to handle this logic in your code, `hibernate` can do this for you. Set `hbm2ddl.auto` property to `create` in `hibernate.cfg.xml`, hibernate will drop the existing table and create a new one every time you run the application. If you don't want to create a new table anymore, set the property to `update`, hibernate will append data on the table.

```
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
```